# Galera DB wsrep failing to connect

Tags: mysql, database, connection, cluster-computing, galera

So basically I'm trying to initialize the first node, but it fails and gives me this error:

```
2016-11-29 21:46:44 15882 [ERROR] WSREP: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 110: failed to reach primary view: 110 (Connection timed out)
     at gcomm/src/pc.cpp:connect():158
2016-11-29 21:46:44 15882 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:gcs_core_open():208: Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed out)
2016-11-29 21:46:44 15882 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1380: Failed to open channel 'MySQL' at 'gcomm://XXX.32.17.249,XXX.69.63.203': -110 (Connection timed out)
2016-11-29 21:46:44 15882 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Connection timed out
2016-11-29 21:46:44 15882 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect(gcomm://XXX.32.17.249,XXX.69.63.203) failed: 7
2016-11-29 21:46:44 15882 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Command: `service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster`

Full config:

```
# Galera
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name=MySQL
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://XXX.32.17.249,XXX.69.63.203"
wsrep_node_name=MySQL_EU
wsrep_node_address="XXX.32.17.249"
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
```

*These servers are in different regions

Comment: What's the ping time between regions?  Did you increase any timeouts?

Comment: After few days I figured that you need to start the first node with empty gconn:// and it worked.

Comment: Wow, that finally worked for me too. Man, I was getting annoyed. Thanks!!

Comment: Another note: if cluster fails, you need to bootstrap it from the first node

Comment: If this is happening to other than the bootstrap node. The issue was the firewall for me. I tried turning off SELinux by editing "/etc/selinux/conf" file and restarted the server but didn't help. I had to turn off via "systemctl stop firewalld" (CentOS). The primary node didn't have issue as it was coming up in bootstrap mode. I did check the ports to the other nodes with "telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 3306"

Answer (score 2):

The first node has to be started with an empty gconn:// can be found in the documentation.

Another issue could be:
"If this is happening to other than the bootstrap node. The issue was the firewall for me. I tried turning off SELinux by editing "/etc/selinux/conf" file and restarted the server but didn't help. I had to turn off via "systemctl stop firewalld" (CentOS). The primary node didn't have issue as it was coming up in bootstrap mode. I did check the ports to the other nodes with "telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 3306"" – blokeish